# Formula Field for Unique Contact ID Counter for Reports in Salesforce Classic not Lightning

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

Part of the org app has yet to transition to Lightning, so this question relates to Classic and Reports. I need to get a Unique Count of  PICKLIST FIELD linked to a Parent Object 
I can't use UNIQUE COUNT ID as it's CLASSIC. I'm hoping someone can assist,

Need to create a report in salesforce on Campaign Members with the report type Campaign Members with Contacts that shows a unique count on;
Parent Object(Campaign Members) 
with Field 'Status': Value = 'Volunteers' - who are both active and inactive 
Per quarter
Currently, the Classic report with a cross filter shows the same volunteer multiple times.

My approach was to create a Formula Field on the Campaign Member Object.

The Formula, Datatype (Number), Advanced Formula
**No of Volunteers CM (Number) = ISPICKVAL(Status, "Volunteer")**

I'm getting the following error message
Error: Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Number)
 
I'd welcome your input. Thanks

Comment: You can try `IF(ISPICKVAL(Status, "Volunteer"), 1, 0)` but if same contact appears multiple times in campaigns you might still have duplicates. And technically Contact is the parent here, Campaign Members is a rel. list. And you might have more luck on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/, better for non-coding questions

Comment: @eyescream Still not showing unique numbers. Thanks for trying. Yes I think as the Contact is the parent, it is throwing up some problems. I'll let you know if find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way by switching between Classic and Lightning and then back.

As "Report builder" in Lightning was actually based on the "Classic Report builder". Reports & Dashboards were never built ground-up for Lightning. 2/ With that understanding, we can follow the rules:
(a). A report created in Lightning could not be accessed in Classic but
(b). A report created in Classic could be accessed AND edited in Lightning.

I created the report in Classic, then switched to Lightning to add the Unique Counter to the Full Name Column.

It is important that when editing the Column you don't put the cursor on the downward cursor on the top right of the column (still shows the Classic options) but instead to go to the EDIT button on the top right of the page and then go back to column to edit where the Unique Values option show up. Equally, if you switch back to Classic the Unique Value is lost. So either export data & save or each time you will have to switch back to Lightning and choose the Unique Values option to view the report.

Alternatively, just do the report in Lightning in the first place!!! ;-)

Thanks @eyescream for assisting too.